# Jquery selector for checkboxes not getting correct items

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have a page that contains `x` number of rows, dynamically generated from a database. Each form has a set of checkboxes and a save button. Everything else is working correctly, but it seems like no matter which save button I click, it's pulling in the selections from all the forms (after the first one; whichever save button I click first has the correct selections.) Where am I going wrong here?

```
<table>
    <tr class="even">
        <td class="checksCol">
            <input type="checkbox" name="pages_new" id="new_10" value="10">salads<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="pages_new" id="new_9" value="9">sandwiches<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="pages_new" id="new_7" value="7">sides<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="pages_new" id="new_14" value="14">soups<br>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd">
        <td colspan="3">
            <input type="button" class="saveDisclaimer" id="saveDisclaimer_new" value="Save">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table>
    <tr class="even">
        <td class="checksCol">
            <input type="checkbox" name="pages_2" id="2_10" value="10">salads<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="pages_2" id="2_9" value="9">sandwiches<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="pages_2" id="2_7" value="7">sides<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="pages_2" id="2_14" value="14">soups<br>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd">
        <td colspan="3">
            <input type="button" class="saveDisclaimer" id="saveDisclaimer_2" value="Save">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.saveDisclaimer').click( function(e) {
    var id = this.id.split("_").pop();
    console.log("id: " + id);
    var pages = [];

    $('input[name="pages_"+id]:checked').each(function() {
      pages.push(this.value);
    });
    console.log("pages from input name=pages_" + id);
    console.log(pages);

    e.preventDefault();
  });

});
```

[JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/fufemugevu/edit?html,js,console,output) - select a few checkboxes from the first form; click save. The console shows the correct selections. Then, without deselecting the checkboxes, click a few in the second form, and click the second save button. The console shows ALL checkboxes that are still selected, not just the ones that go with the particular save button.

Comment: I see multiple tables and zero forms

Comment: I'm not sure why that matters; I'm not actually trying to submit anything.

Comment: Looks like you are selecting on the `.saveDisclaimer` class. You would need to lower the scope of your selection to just the form you want to select. I would suggest appending a unique counter on each generated form id so that you can select only the `.saveDisclaimer` class for your chosen form, something like `$(form1.saveDisclaimer)`, `$(form2.saveDisclaimer)` etc

Comment: @MasterYoda - If you look inside, I'm pulling an id from the save button to use in the selector for the checkboxes. I've used this technique before and it works flawlessly for everything except checkboxes.

Comment: Look closely at the syntax highlighting here in the question: `'input[name="pages_"+id]:checked'` here, `+id` is part of the string literal, it is not concatenating the `id` variable.

Comment: $('input[name="pages_"+id]:checked') should read $('input[name="pages_'+id+'"]:checked)

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic due to typos

Comment: [.pop()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_pop.asp)... are you sure your console log is not showing you the error already?

Comment: @j08691 - I'm not sure I understand. Yes, there was a mistake in my selector. That's not a typo; it's a mistake, and I'm betting I'm not the only person who's made that mistake.

Comment: Your mistake is a typo. Incorrect concatenation. I don't see how that would help anyone other than you. It's very specific to your problem.

Comment: @j08691 - a typo is something that I mistyped, but actually know how to do - a misspelling, perhaps. This is not a typo, it's a misunderstanding of how to generate a dynamic selector.

Comment: Let me put it this way, your error wasn't in your logic. That was fine. Your error was in the way you typed out the text of your selector in that your quotes were in the wrong place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not creating the string correctly. Try:

```
$('input[name="pages_' + id + '"]:checked').....
```

Comment: Thank you. I had a feeling there was something wrong with that part, but  couldn't figure out what.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple. You have double quotes inside sigle quotes:

```
'input[name="pages_"+id]:checked'
```

It should be:

```
'input[name="pages_'+id+'"]:checked'
```

Comment: How is your answer any different from the other one from 11 minutes ago?

Comment: I went to the bathroom, returned, posted my answer and was already answered.

Comment: I hesitate to even begin to think what you were doing in the can for 11 minutes

Comment: @j08691, I apologize for my intestinal tendencies, before I read a magazine, now I take my cell phone to the throne... my legs even fall asleep sometimes... :b